# What was the reasoning behind the design choice to make RecursiveTask's compute method protected?

Tags: java, fork-join

In the Fork/Join framework, `RecursiveTask<T>`'s `compute()` method is declared as `protected`, rather than being package default.   You're left with options of override only including `protected` and `public` (package default will not compile.)

Is there a reason that protected was selected and not package default?  I'd be interested to know, as this might help me to understand an aspect of the framework of which I am not yet aware.

Answer (score 0):

If `compute()` had package access in `RecursiveTask<T>`, it couldn't be overridden.  [JLS §8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) spells out when a method overrides another; if the method in the superclass has package access, a `compute()` method in the subclass overrides it only if it is in the same package as the superclass.  Since the superclass, `RecursiveTask<T>`, is in `java.util.concurrent`, your concrete subclass could only override it if your class was also in `java.util.concurrent`--which you wouldn't want to do, and Java probably wouldn't let you do.